# How do you allow the user to type any variation of a word and it match my variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please see my code in Python - just started.

```
my_name = input("What is your name? ")
my_secondname = input("What is your second name? ")
age = int(input("What is your age? "))

measurement = input("What unit of measurement would you like to use, Imperial or Metric? (imp or met) ")
if measurement == "imp" or "Imperial" or "imperial" or "Imp":
    imp_weight = int(input("What is your weight? (Numbers only lbs) "))
    imp_height = int(input("What is your height? (Numbers only inches) "))
```

I would like the user to be able to type any variation of imperial. Ive looked everywhere for this, and to be honest im not even sure how to google it properly so i apologise if this is a duplicate question!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!
Ryan

Comment: `if a == b or c or d or e` doesn't do what you think it does. It checks if any of `a==b`, `bool(c)`, `bool(d)`, `bool(e)` are true. Taking the `bool` of a non-empty string will always return `True`, so your if statement is essentially `if True:`

Comment: `if measurement.lower() in ["imp", "imperial"]:`

Comment: force it to be a certain way, like `if measurement.lower() == 'imp' or 'imperial':`

Comment: @APhillips this will always return `True`.

Comment: @CDJB you are right, your edit above is what I was thinking. Thank you.

Comment: but if you want a complex pattern matching I would recommend you to use `re.match(r'im.*',measurement.lower())`